# cannot get label to be inline with angular-ui-select object

Tags: angular-ui-select

I am trying to get a label to be to the left of an angular-ui-select dropdown but it keeps appearing below the label no matter what I try. I recently pulled down the latest angular-ui-select. I am using the selectize theme but the same thing happened with the bootstrap theme.

Am I doing something wrong in my HTML? I just don't see it.

Here's my HTML body:

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="acct">
        <label for="acctList">Account:</label>
        <ui-select id="acctList" ng-model="acctList.selected" style="width: 250px;" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" title="Choose an account">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search an account in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="account in acctList | filter: $select.search">
                <span ng-bind-html="account.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any help is much appreciated. thx

Answer (score 4):

After doing more searches and experimentation and using Firebug, I found out that ui-select is made up of div's. I was able to place the label on the left of the dropdown by adding:

```
display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle
```

to the style attribute of the `ui-select`.

(unable to post picture)